# Lookup, insert if necessary in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB 10.2.32. There's a dynamic lookup table - integer autoincrement primary key `ID`, varchar `Name` with a unique index on it. Question: is it possible to implement a logic of "if the name is there, return the corresponding ID, if not, insert and return the generated ID" **in one SQL statement**?

Nonstandard, MySQL specific SQL extensions are very welcome. `insert ignore` and `insert... on duplicate key` come pretty close, except neither returns the ID. But I'm hardly up to date on the latest flavor of the vendor SQL.

EDIT: also `insert...returning`, but that requires MariaDB 10.5.

A stored procedure won't work for me - it's a shared hosting setup, the prod server doesn't allow SPs.

Using PHP 7.3 with Mysqli.

EDIT: *I know how to do it in multiple statements*. The question is, can one do it in one.

Comment: You'll probably need a second call to retrieve the inserted ID using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, unless the API retrieves the ID in the same call. JDBC can usually do that if you specify you want the created keys. What language/client API are you using? In case it does exist, I don't know how to retrieve the ID, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's nothing that will do this in a single statement.

Comment: You'll need to do it with multiple queries, and should use a transaction to ensure it's atomic.

Comment: You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, then do a `SELECT` query to get the ID for the username.

Comment: In the IODKU, `SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID)`, then do `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.